# Unable to run a program in sublime text: [Finished in x seconds]

Tags: java, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I was making a java program in sublime text.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World !");
    }
}
```

so, it prints out:
`[Finished in 512 ms]`

I don't know why does not it execute my program and tells only the time taken.

Comment: In all likihood you're trying to use the built in build system for Java that ships with Sublime, which only compiles a single Java file to bytecode but doesn't actually run it. So you're only going to see any sort of output if your code is broken. To use Java with Sublime you need to be familiar enough with the Java ecosystem to know how to compile and run code so that you can tell Sublime how to do it.

Comment: I recommend checking out the [`Javatar`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Javatar) package. It makes Sublime much more like a Java IDE (for example, Eclipse), than it currently is. However, as your modules start getting larger and larger, you'll start needing Java-native build systems and things like import managers. Javatar has some of that. OTOH, it hasn't been developed for the past 5 years, so you may want to look for other [Java packages](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/java).

Answer (score 0):

**Sublime text** is a text editor that only *builds* i.e *compiles* your file and don't run it. Since the compiled java files are not in the **.exe** format because java is a platform-independent language. Many OS doesn't support **.exe** format such as macOS. In a nutshell, you can't a compiled java file just by double-clicking on it. So to run a java file, you have to open **cmd**. Navigate to the folder where your java file is stored. Type-

```
cd foldername
```

If the folder is not on your **User** folder. Type-

```
cd folderpath
```

After that, type-

```
java filename
```

And you'll see the output.

**Edit:** ***foldername** and **folderpath** are not a keyword, they simply mean the file name and the folder path respectively.*